# force php file to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a file called video.php on my domain but want it on my subdomain.

now its like `www.domain.com/video.php?id=parameter&fewotherparamer=1233`

and I want to change it to

```
video.domain.com/video.php?id=parameter&fewotherparamer=1233
```

how would this be possible? I already tried to find out using google and the searchfunction here, but didn't find the point.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add these directives to .htaccess file in domain.com root directory (or virtual host config) and make sure you enabled mod_rewrite module

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^video.php$ http://video.domain.com/video.php [R=301,NC,L ]
```